# Suitable Data Model design (RDBMS) for multiple permutations of data

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, rdbms, dimensional-modeling

I'm building an Analytics application where we track the conversions for a companies marketing Campaigns. A conversion is if they go to a supermarket and buy the product. If the company is Heinz, they might run Campaigns for different products, so Campaigns might be:

- Baked Beans
- Tomato Soup
- Ketchup

These are online Campaigns so they can have different Mediums such as:

- Website
- Facebook page
- Flash Banner Ad
- Mobile App Ad

And if someone buys a product, it's bought via a Supermarket such as:

- Walmart
- Asda
- Safeway
- Kroger

And we're tracking conversions for all these. The analytics application needs to display conversions data for any combination of the above. So for instance, I might need to show conversions...

- for Baked Beans.
- for Baked beans from the Facebook page.
- for the Supermarket Walmart but for all Campaigns & Mediums.
- for Walmart made from the Facebook page but for all Campaigns.
- for Ketchup made via the Flash Banner Ad and for Safeway.

To make the analytics fast, we're avoiding dealing with the raw data (millions of records), but storing an aggregated version of the data stored on a per day basis. So for the 12th September say, I can stored that we had 12 conversions for Baked Beans, 6 conversions (for all products) were made via the website, and Walmart had 8 conversions, and these could go in 3 separate tables (called Campaigns, Mediums, and Supermarkets). But if I need to know conversions for Ketchup made via the Facebook page and for Walmart, storing in separate tables obvious won't work.

I'm struggling to come up with a data model that can support the above. I'm using a standard Relational database (MySQL). Perhaps there is a better strategy to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a better strategy. It's called **Dimensional Modeling**, or Star Schema.

You store one table, called the *Fact Table*, which has columns for Campaign, Medium, and Supermarket.

For each of these attributes, the column in the Fact Table is a foreign key to a *Dimension Table*. One dimension table for each, Campaigns, Mediums, and Supermarkets.

In your case, to avoid millions of rows, you could add a fourth column to the fact table, `conversions`. Increment the count when you get a conversion (as opposed to adding another row).

Here's an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE FactTable (
  campaign_id INT,
  medium_id INT,
  supermarket_id INT,
  conversions INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (campaign_id, medium_id, supermarket_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES Campaigns(campaign_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (medium_id) REFERENCES Mediums(medium_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (supermarket_id) REFERENCES Supermarkets(supermarket_id)
);
```

Then you can query for all conversions:

- for Baked Beans.

  ```
  SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM FactTable
  JOIN Campaigns USING (campaign_id) 
  WHERE campaign = 'Baked Beans';
  ```
- for Baked beans from the Facebook page.

  ```
  SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM FactTable
  JOIN Campaigns USING (campaign_id) 
  JOIN Mediums USING (medium_id)
  WHERE campaign = 'Baked Beans' AND medium = 'Facebook';
  ```
- for the Supermarket Walmart but for all Campaigns & Mediums.

  ```
  SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM FactTable
  JOIN Supermarkets USING (supermarket_id)
  WHERE supermarket = 'Walmart';
  ```
- for Walmart made from the Facebook page but for all Campaigns.

  ```
  SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM FactTable
  JOIN Mediums USING (medium_id)
  JOIN Supermarkets USING (supermarket_id)
  WHERE medium = 'Facebook' AND supermarket = 'Walmart';
  ```
- for Ketchup made via the Flash Banner Ad and for Safeway.

  ```
  SELECT SUM(conversions) FROM FactTable
  JOIN Campaigns USING (campaign_id)
  JOIN Mediums USING (medium_id)
  JOIN Supermarkets USING (supermarket_id)
  WHERE campaign = 'Ketchup' AND medium = 'Flash Banner Ad' AND supermarket = 'Safeway';
  ```

Check out [books by Ralph Kimball](http://www.amazon.com/Ralph-Kimball/e/B000AP5ULY) for more on Dimensional Modeling.

Comment: Easily in the Top 5 best Stackoverflow answers I've ever had! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Not only a good answer, but very well-stated.  I would only add that in many cases, the client application has the integer id's (or some sort of uuid for a public api) embedded in the control that displays the names. So no need for the joins...just the WHERE clause filtering on the id(s).  Even faster.

Comment: @NaturalData, yes, that's a good optimization, I was showing the joins because it illustrates the role of the dimension tables pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that by trying to manipulate your data structure to avoid dealing with the raw data, you are increasing complexity and reducing flexibility for very little real benefit.  With proper indexes and properly tuned queries, querying millions of records should take very little time.  I've queried tables with half a billion records on multiple fields and gotten results in under 20ms.

Put your effort into tuning instead of designing new data structures, and you'll be thankful when whoever is consuming these analytics needs the data in some slightly different format that makes your well-planned design obsolete.